# Update JSON attribute after scope variable update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following JSON array in my controlle

```
$scope.companyExcelColumns = [
  {
    label: 'Name', checked: true, disabled: true, id:'nameExcel'
  },
  {
    label: 'value', checked: true, disabled: $scope.records > 1000 ? true : false, id: 'valueExcel'
  }
];
```

Initially the $scope.records is 0, later on it is changing but the the disabled attribute is not updating, is there a workaround ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not a common angular question but rather a programming question. of course value of disabled will not change. it is calculated once and done for.

You could use $watch and watch changes on $scope.records object. when this object changes you can reassign value of disabled.

```
$scope.$watch('records', function(){ disabled = $scope.records.length > 1000})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$watch` method to watch every change of `$scope.records` :

```
$scope.companyExcelColumns = [
  {
    label: 'Name', checked: true, disabled: true, id:'nameExcel'
  },
  {
    label: 'value', checked: true, disabled: $scope.records > 1000 ? true : false, id: 'valueExcel'
  }
];

$scope.$watch('records', function(newValue, oldValue){
  $scope.companyExcelColumns = [
    {
      label: 'Name', checked: true, disabled: true, id:'nameExcel'
    },
    {
      label: 'value', checked: true, disabled: newValue > 1000 ? true : false, id: 'valueExcel'
    }
  ];
})
```